# Connecting to a Microsoft Access database from C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, authentication

I'm working on a project in C#, which includes a Log in form, however as of yet 
I haven't managed to get the connection working. My

```
OleDBConnection
```

object has the connection string

```
@"Provider=SQLOLEDB;" + @"Data Source=" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase + "DATABASE_NAME.accdb" + @"Persist Security Info=False;"
```

( Messy I know )

Note: I have tried other providers

```
Microsoft.Jet.4.0
Microsoft.ACE.12.0
```

both with no avail.
I'm just trying to connect my C# code to the Access database which is in it's Debug folder.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Microsoft.ACE.12.0 is the one to use, what exception/stack results from you doing so?

Comment: "The 'Microsoft.ACE.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine..."

Comment: Install it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise I had to download it aha. Will try now.

Comment: @ChristianLoizou - Two notes: **(1)** If the file is indeed an .accdb file then "Jet" won't work. Jet only supports .mdb files. **(2)** The correct provider name is `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` (you're missing the "OLEDB" part).

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the heads up on the missing part. I hadn’t noticed and it turned out to be a mistake in my source.

Comment: @ChristianLoizou - So has your issue been resolved?

Comment: @GordThompson not exactly. I’ve tried downloading both 32 bit and 64 bit AccessDatabaseEngine and somehow I’ve managed to get both 32 and 64 bit office software on my computer. I’m sure you already know that I can’t mix and match the version of the software I’m getting so I’m just trying to figure out how to remove 64 bit

Comment: Print out and inspect the resulting conection string - I think you are missing a `;` before "Persist Security Info". While you are seeing the connstring, is the path correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't heard of ConnectionString, it very handy website to find correct connection string for any provider.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/

One thing to note is, not all the provider driver may be installed on your computer, so you need to install them first before using that provider.